# How can I move element to the block using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I need to click on 'element B' and move it into a 'block 2'
html:

```
<div class="element" >
  <span class="name">element A</span>
</div>
<div class="element" >
  <span class="name">element B</span>
</div>
<div class="element" >
  <span class="name">element C</span>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="block-name">
      <span class="name">block 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="card-cover">
    <div class="block-name">
      <span class="name">block 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get and click on the 'element B'

```
cy.get('.element', {timeout:20000})
  .contains('element B')
  .click({force:true})
```

Also I can get and click on the 'block 2'

```
cy.get('.block', {timeout:20000}) 
  .contains('block 2') 
  .click({force:true})
```

But I cannot understand how I move element A to the block 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed plugin 'cypress-drag-drop'

cy.get('.element:contains("element B")').drag('.block:contains("block 2")',  { timeout: 20000})